# nix-build: bash permission denied

Tags: nix

I'm trying to learn to write Nix expressions, and I thought about doing my own very simple "Hello World!" (as is tradition).

So I have my dir with only this `default.nix` file :

```
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}}:
derivation {
    system = "x86_64-linux";
    name = "simple-bash-derivation-helloworld";
    builder = pkgs.bash;
    args = [ "-c" "echo 'Hello World' > $out" ];
}
```

Here is what I get when I try to build it:

```
nix-build
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/3grmahx3ih4c50asj84p7xnpqpj32n5s-simple-bash-derivation-helloworld.drv
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/6psl3rc92311w37c1n6nj0a6jac16hv1-simple-bash-derivation-helloworld’
while setting up the build environment: executing ‘/nix/store/wb34dgkpmnssjkq7yj4qbjqxpnapq0lw-bash-4.4-p12’: Permission denied
builder for ‘/nix/store/3grmahx3ih4c50asj84p7xnpqpj32n5s-simple-bash-derivation-helloworld.drv’ failed with exit code 1
error: build of ‘/nix/store/3grmahx3ih4c50asj84p7xnpqpj32n5s-simple-bash-derivation-helloworld.drv’ failed
```

Removing the `args` line yields the same issue.

Why do I get a permission issue?
What would be the correct way to make a simple derivation just doing a bash echo?

Please note that this is a learning exercise: I do not want to use `stdenv.mkDerivation` here for example.

I am running `nix-env (Nix) 1.11.9` on an Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `ls` command on `/nix/store/wb34dgkpmnssjkq7yj4qbjqxpnapq0lw-bash-4.4-p12` and you will see it's a directory rather than an executable file (pointing to `$out` of the `pkgs.bash` derivation). If you wanted to refer to `bash` binary you would use:

```
builder = "${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash";
```

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much!
Is there somewhere where this kind of things are documented?
I wish there was a nix IDE with some kind of autocompletion.

Comment: @DavidGrayson The manual does not detail the content of packages

Comment: The manual says that `builder` needs to be an executable, and you tried to assign it to be a directory.

Comment: Ok, out path can be found with `nix-env -qa --out-path bash`, but the package need to be installed or of course the path doesn't exist. So it seems trial and error will have to do.

Comment: Oh, the way I would find the path to bash is by doing something like `bash = pkgs.bash;` temporarily in the derivation I am trying to build, and then running `nix-build -A myrecipe.bash`, where `myrecipe` is the attribute path to the thing you were trying to build.  So just append `.bash` to your previous build command.